# Xamarin IOS - HttpClient and localhost

Tags: ios, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to access from an IOS Simulator to my local web api.

I configured my IOS application to allow non secure locale urls :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

But when I try a post call, I receive a **404 HTTP ERROR**.

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
                var uri = new Uri(url);
                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                try
                {
                    StringContent queryString = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, queryString, cts.Token);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new HttpRequestException("Unable to get data from backend");
                    }
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    throw new WebException(ex.Message);
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
                {
                    throw new TaskCanceledException(ex.Message);
                }

            }
```

The url look like **http://localhost:5000/api/MyController**.

In my controller, I have a simple GET method that return a list of objects.

Of course, If I try to access to the webapi from Safari Web browser in the simulator... It works.

If somebody already face this problem...

**EDIT 1 :**

This is not related at all with ATS because I use managed HTTPClient in my Xamarin IOS App configuration but still the error.

Comment: I had this to my ATS exceptions, still the issue